# How to define a ternary operator in Scala which preserves leading tokens?

Tags: scala, language-features, scala-2.8

I'm writing a code generator which produces Scala output.

I need to emulate a ternary operator in such a way that the tokens leading up to '?' remain intact.

e.g. convert the expression `c ? p : q` to `c something`. The simple `if(c) p else q` fails my criteria, as it requires putting `if(` before `c`.

My first attempt (still using c/p/q as above) is

```
c match { case(true) => p; case _ => q }
```

another option I found was:

```
class ternary(val g: Boolean => Any) { def |: (b:Boolean) = g(b) }

implicit def autoTernary (g: Boolean => Any): ternary = new ternary(g)
```

which allows me to write:

```
c |: { b: Boolean => if(b) p else q }
```

I like the overall look of the second option, but is there a way to make it less verbose?

Thanks

Comment: e.g. something using '_' in place of b:Boolean would be nice, but I couldn't get anything to work right

Comment: See `BooleanW#?` from Scalaz: http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/BooleanW.scala.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even though the syntax doesn't evaluate in the expected order--it binds the conditional to the first option!--you can make your own ternary operator like this:

```
class IfTrue[A](b: => Boolean, t: => A) { def |(f: => A) = if (b) t else f }
class MakeIfTrue(b: => Boolean) { def ?[A](t: => A) = new IfTrue[A](b,t) }
implicit def autoMakeIfTrue(b: => Boolean) = new MakeIfTrue(b)
```

The trick is to interpret `?` as a method on a `MakeIfTrue` object that binds the condition to the object to return in the "true" case.  The resulting `IfTrue` object now uses the `|` method as a request to evaluate the condition, returning the stored true option if the condition is true, or the just-passed-in one if it's false.

Note that I've used stuff like `=> A` instead of just `A`--by-name parameters--in order to not evaluate the expression unless it's actually used.  Thus, you'll only evaluate the side that you actually need (just like an if statement).

Let's see it in action:

```
scala> List(1,3,2).isEmpty ? "Empty" | "Nonempty"
res0: java.lang.String = Nonempty

scala> (4*4 > 14) ? true | false
res1: Boolean = true

scala> class Scream(s: String) { println(s.toUpperCase + "!!!!") }
defined class Scream

scala> true ? new Scream("true") | new Scream("false")
TRUE!!!!
res3: Scream = Scream@1ccbdf7
```

(P.S. To avoid confusion with the Actor library `?`, you probably ought to call it something else like `|?`.)

Comment: Doh, too slow. I was in the progress of typing something similar to this up, only to get the dreaded "2 new answers" message

Comment: @Jackson: Interesting alternatives are still worthwhile!

Comment: Nice! Only thing I'll change is ? to |? to get the lowest operator priority.

Comment: @Alex: Just keep in mind that this has a lot more overhead than an if-statement.  Performance-critical code should still use ifs (which are ~40x faster in my microbenchmarks--but it's ~40 ns vs. ~1 ns on a modern 3GHzish machine, so you'd really need to be doing this many millions of times per second before you'd care).

Comment: Did you enable optimizations when benchmarking? Shouldn't inlining get rid of the overhead? Possibly making some classes/methods final might help compile-time inlining (which the Scala compiler does).

Comment: BTW, you begin by mentioning a problem with order of evaluation, but I don't understand your remark. Your code should perform the evaluation in the right order. BTW, you don't need to pass the boolean around by-name, since it must be evaluated anyway.

Answer (score 13):

Let's keep it simple:

Java:

```
tmp = (a > b) ? a : b;
```

Scala:

```
tmp = if (a > b) a else b
```

Besides simplicity, it is clear and fast because: do not allocate objects you don't need, keeps the garbage collector out of equation (as it always should be) and makes better use of processor caches.

Comment: This is my favourite answer. Your explanation is as simple as the solution.

Comment: This solves a different problem, not the one stated in the question.

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like this

```
sealed trait TernaryOperand[A] {
  def >(q: => A): A
}

case class TernarySecond[A](val p: A) extends TernaryOperand[A] {
  def >(q: => A) = p
}

case class TernaryThird[A]() extends TernaryOperand[A] {
  def >(q: => A) = q
}

implicit def ternary(c: Boolean) = new {
  def ?[A](p: => A): TernaryOperand[A] = if (c) TernarySecond(p) else TernaryThird()
}

val s1 = true ? "a" > "b"
println(s1) //will print "a"

val s2 = false ? "a" > "b"
println(s2) //will print "b"
```

This code converts any boolean value to an anonymous type that has a method called `?`. Depending on the value of the boolean, this method will either return `TernarySecond` or `TernaryThird`. They both have a method called `>` which returns the second operand or the third one respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operator which adds my improvement to the best of Rex Kerr’s and Michel Krämer’s implementations:

- My improvement to use Scala’s new value class to avoid boxing overhead.
- Call by-name on 2nd and 3rd operands so only the chosen one is evaluated.
- Michel’s call by-value on the 1st (Boolean) operand to avoid by-name overhead; it is always evaluated.
- Rex’s concrete class for the condition to avoid any anonymous class overhead.
- Michel’s evaluation of the condition to determine which class to construct to avoid of overhead of a two argument constructor.

.

```
sealed trait TernaryResult[T] extends Any {
  def |(op3: => T): T
}

class Ternary2ndOperand[T](val op2: T) extends AnyVal with TernaryResult[T] {
  def |(op3: => T) = op2
}

class Ternary3rdOperand[T](val op2: T) extends AnyVal with TernaryResult[T] {
  def |(op3: => T) = op3
}

class Ternary(val op1:Boolean) extends AnyVal {
   def ?[A](op2: => A): TernaryResult[A] = if (op1) new Ternary2ndOperand(op2) else new Ternary3rdOperand(op2)
}

object Ternary {
   implicit def toTernary(condition: Boolean) = new Ternary(condition)
}
```

Note the improvement over `if else` is not just the 6 characters saved. With Scala IDE’s syntax coloring on keywords being the same (e.g. purple) for `if`, `else`, `null`, and `true`, there is better contrast in some cases (which isn't shown by the syntax coloring below as currently rendered on this site):

```
if (cond) true else null
cond ? true | null
```